# InkCanvas Recognize Only Numbers

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

I am making a math worksheet app where you can write in the answer below the problem using an `InkCanvas`. The problem is that if you write a "1" the way most people do it looks like "|", and is recognized as a vertical bar. It seems there should be some way to set the `InkRecognizerContainer` to recognize only numbers, but I can't find any way to do it. Is this possible?

Here's my current code:

```
var recognitionResults = await inkRecognizerContainer.RecognizeAsync(inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer, InkRecognitionTarget.All)
string answerString = string.Empty;

foreach (var result in recognitionResults)
{
    answerString += result.GetTextCandidates()[0];
}

int submittedAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(answerString);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that if you write a "1" the way most people do it looks like "|", and is recognized as a vertical bar

This should be related to the handwriting recognizer you chosen, check the official [Simple inking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk)

The second scenario show us how to recognize handwriting from ink strokes using different handwriting recognizer

This is the result from *Microsoft English (US) Handwriting Recognizer*:

[image: Recognizer Result]

> It seems there should be some way to set the InkRecognizerContainer to recognize only numbers

There is no such setting for [InkRecognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.input.inking.inkrecognizer.aspx) to recognize only number, the only possible way is to check the result and notify user to rewrite again for better recognition effect.

Comment: Huh. That is the recognizer I'm using. Will try later today.

Comment: Is there any way to bring Microsoft English (US) Handwriting Recognizer with app? User can use it immediately without install in Region and Language